# Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'varView'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode7.3

Please help fast

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    DestVC.varView = indexPath.row // This is the error line

}
```

The error is

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'varView'

Comment: var DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as YourViewController
change UIViewController with your destinationviewcontroller

Answer (score 3):

change UIViewController with your destination view controller.
for e.g your destinationviewcontroller name is `YourViewController`
and also use if let for safely unwrap

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if let DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YouViewController  {

var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

DestVC.varView = indexPath.row 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
var DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
```

with

```
var DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as YourDestinationClassName
```

and make sure that there is a `varView` member available in that class

Hope this will help :)